# react redux applyMiddleware is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Couldn't spot any flaw in my code myself, I got error of

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.applyMiddleware) is not a
>   function

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'react-redux'
import { promiseMiddleware } from './middleware'

const defaultState = {
    appName: 'conduit',
}

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'HOME_PAGE_LOADED':
            return { ...state, articles: action.payload.articles }
    }
    return state
}

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware)

const store = createStore(reducer, middleware)

export default store
```

Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: don't those [come from redux, not react-redux?](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html)

Comment: What does promiseMiddleware look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your imports mixed up.  `createStore` and `applyMiddleware` are part of the main Redux package, not React-Redux.  You need:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call promise middleware like this

```
const middleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware())
```

i.e- Use function brackets after promiseMiddleware text.

See documentation here-
[image]

Comment: have you installed promiseMiddleware by npm?

Comment: I have used this middleware in one of my projects. I installed it through npm and it works fine. If you want i can share code